# Python random.shuffle() on a list of lists returns a list of identical lists

Tags: python

In my script I need to generate a simple list of [1,2,3,4] values and then shuffle each one of those lists inside this list individually. I used random.shuffle() function which works fine on single arrays, but when I try to use it in a for loop the output is a list of shuffled arrays, but all of them identical:

> [3, 1, 2, 4]
>   [3, 1, 2, 4]
>   [3, 1, 2, 4]
>   etc...

I have tried running the script with different python versions (2.7, 3.6) but the problem persists.

Here is a simplified code that represents the issue:

```
import random

numbers_list = [1,2,3,4]
#make a list of 10 numbers_list
list_of_lists = [numbers_list]*10

#shuffle every list inside list_of_lists
for i in list_of_lists:
    random.shuffle(i)

#print every list from list_of_lists
for a in list_of_lists:
    print(a)
```

Running the script multiple times results in different lists, but they always consist of a repeated one array. What can I do to fix it? Is it an issue with random.shuffle() or my script? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At first glance, I'd say that you write 10 references to the sam object in the List. But I don't know the operation you use here `[numbers_list]*10 `. Did you test this syntax with other objects that return memory adresses so you can see if they are the same object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
list_of_lists = [numbers_list]*10
```

This creates a list of 10 references to the same list (`numbers_list`). Any change you make to any of the lists is reflected in all 10 copies - because they're the same list.

Do something like this instead:

```
list_of_lists = [numbers_list.copy() for _ in range(10)]
```

Comment: So I guess that using [something] * number makes sense only if "something" is a number or a constant because if you do that like I did, you create a list of references that change together? Also thanks, that solved it.

Comment: Yup that's right. It's a pretty common "gotcha" in python.

Answer (score 0):

Culprit is there:

```
numbers_list = [1,2,3,4]
#make a list of 10 numbers_list
list_of_lists = [numbers_list]*10
```

as now `list_of_lists` is in fact ONE list repeated 10 times, you could avoid that using `.copy` method as already shown or by replacing:

```
list_of_lists = [numbers_list]*10
```

with

```
list_of_lists = [list(numbers_list) for _ in range(10)]
```

or

```
list_of_lists = [numbers_list[:] for _ in range(10)]
```

First one might be readed I want 10 times new `list` based on `numbers_list` and second harness so-called slicing.